# How to build Hive as a service and metastore using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hive, hive-metastore, metastore

this is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: master
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
      - "7077:7077"
    networks:
      - spark-network
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    volumes:
      - jupyter-notebooks:/jupyter-notebooks  

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: worker-1
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - spark-network
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - jupyter-notebooks:/jupyter-notebooks
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
  jupyter:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    container_name: jupyter
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - jupyter-notebooks:/home/jovyan/work
      - ./JDBC_Driver:/Drivers/SQL_Sever/jdbc
    networks:
      - spark-network
    depends_on:
      - spark-worker-1
      - hive
      - postgres
  sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: sql-server-container
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: Mo*012105
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - sql-server-data:/var/opt/mssql
    networks:
      - spark-network 
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: hive
      POSTGRES_USER: hiveuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: hivepassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      postgres_net:
  hive:
    image: apache/hive:3.1.3
    container_name: hive
    environment:
      - HIVE_METASTORE_URI=thrift://postgres:9083
      - HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"  # Hive server2 port
      - "9083:9083"    # Hive Metastore port
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./emails.csv:/data/emails.csv
    networks:
      spark-network:
      postgres_net:
volumes:
  jupyter-notebooks:
  sql-server-data:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  spark-network:
  postgres_net:
```

and this is the error that i have got from hive service logs:

```
Initialization script completed
2023-09-11 22:02:34 schemaTool completed
2023-09-11 22:02:34 [WARN] Failed to create directory: /home/hive/.beeline
2023-09-11 22:02:34 No such file or directory
2023-09-11 22:02:34 + '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
2023-09-11 22:02:34 + echo 'Initialized schema successfully..'
2023-09-11 22:02:34 Initialized schema successfully..
2023-09-11 22:02:34 + '[' '' == hiveserver2 ']'
2023-09-11 22:02:34 + '[' '' == metastore ']'
2023-09-11 22:02:34 + exec /opt/hive/bin/hive --skiphadoopversion --skiphbasecp --service
2023-09-11 22:02:37 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
2023-09-11 22:02:37 SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this repo](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive), the metastore is running with a connection to postgresql database